# Dual boot - Lenovo G580, eight windows partitions

Tags: fedora, partition, uefi

I'm trying to install Fedora 24 on Lenovo G580. There are 8 partitions: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3768b575dbf53a3a432713a2d66fdbbb

Can i just shrink sda5 and install linux between sda5 and sda6 (without moving sda6, sda7, sda8)? Will Windows and Lenovo recovery partition work after instalation?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can shrink sda5 and install linux on free space. You can create more 8 partitions, because your HDD has GPT partitioning.  Don't change start sector of sda5 partition, otherwise Windows can't boot.

You can shrink sda5 partition by Gparted program. You can run it on bootable  SystemRescueCd.